# error "A data item was not found in the container" in the nested grid view

Tags: asp.net, linq

In the main gridview `"GridViewTtransmittals"` I have the nested gridview with the name `"GridViewTranstoCon"`.When "GridViewTranstoCon" has data, I have no problem, but when there is not any data for that it returns error `"A data item was not found in the container",` I like it to return null value or have it invisible.
The code is like below:

```
protected void GridViewTtransmittals_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.DataItem == null)
        return;
    TransmittaltoConPresentationModel transmittaltoCon = (TransmittaltoConPresentationModel)e.Row.DataItem;
    GridView g2 = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GridViewTranstoCon");

    if (transmittaltoCon.TranstoCons != null)
    {
        g2.DataSource = transmittaltoCon.TranstoCons;
        g2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

The code for data source of main gridview  "GridViewTtransmittals" comes of below code:

```
private void DisplayTransmittals()
{
    if (_Transmittals.Any())
    {
        var query = from transmittalno in _Transmittals

        select new TransmittaltoConPresentationModel { TransID = transmittalno.TransID,
                   Transmittal = transmittalno.TRANSMITTAL, TranstoCons = from doctranstocon in _DocTranstoCons 
                   where doctranstocon == null || transmittalno.TransID == doctranstocon.Transid
                   select doctranstocon != null ? doctranstocon.tblTranstoCon : null};

        GridViewTtransmittals.DataSource = query;
    }
    else
    {
        GridViewTtransmittals.DataSource = null;
    }
    GridViewTtransmittals.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include this

```
protected void GridViewTtransmittals_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {

   }
}
```